# Order of an element of a permutation group.

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

P4 is permutation group. Then what will be the order of element (1 3)(2 4) of P4?

Comment: It is pretty widely used to denote by $\;S_4\;$ the group of all permutations on a set of four elements. Is this what you meant with $\;P_4\;$ ?

Answer (score 3):

Hint. Try squaring the element.